# Inputting and Outputting Multidimensional Vectors w/ Binary

Tags: c++, file, stl, input

I'm trying to create a simple class for maps in my game. Maps are 2 dimensional vectors made of "tile" structs. I'm trying to figure out the best way to input/output these tiles in rows.

For example, I used to use a .txt based loading format. The .txt file would look like this:

```
1 0 2 0 0 0 2 4 5 6 3 
2 4 5 0 0 0 2 0 0 3 4
0 3 5 2 5 3 0 5 5 3 4
0 2 0 5 0 6 0 5 7 8 4
```

I would then go line by line to find the ID integer of each tile. 1 would represent grass, 0 would mean water, and so on. When the parser would reach the end of a line, it would skip down to the next line of ints.

Now I'm trying to do this via fwrite and fread with binary files and structs instead of ints. How would I go about doing this? All I've seen is how to store an array of structs in a binary file, not how to store a multidimensional array of structs. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**  Yes, I could just store the 2D vector in the file, but that wouldn't allow me to do seamless map loading, which I need. I have large map files, so having 100k tiles loaded at once would hog CPU.

Comment: `fread` and `fwrite` are not c++. use `fstream`.

Comment: @Dani -- Not strictly true.  The C standard is included in the C++ standard, so technically `fread()` and `fwrite()` _are_ C++.  However I certainly agree with you that stream-based i/o is considered to be much better style.

Comment: Ok, thanks guys. I was finally able to find a direction to take this in so I chose XML and RapidXML as explained in [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/232396-c-tile-engine-from-scratch-part-4/) tutorial. I now have a map up and running. :)

Comment: @MichaelJ: That's bullshit. The C++ Standard *sometimes* includes *parts* from a *specific version* of the C Standard. `fread`, `fwrite`, maybe they're in those parts, maybe they're not, but it's pure bullshit to state that the C Standard is included in the C++ Standard. In addition, memory leaks and UB are part of the C++ Standard, but nobody would ever consider recommending them.

Comment: @DeadMG - I'm guessing that you've never actually _read_ a copy of the standard.  I _will_ correct my statement to "The C standard _library_ is included in the C++ standard" which is more correct.  fread() and fwrite() are part of the C standard library.  I don't have a copy of the latest standard, but I have a draft from Feb 2011.  In that text, it is clause 17.2.  It is in any version you look at.  Note: If you read to the end of my previous post, I didn't recommnd use of C I.O -- I merely pointed out that it is legal.  (continued)

Comment: (continued ...)  I don't know what you mean by "memory leaks and UB are part of the C++ Standard".  In what way are memory leaks "in the standard"?  Also, what are "UB"?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your map to be human readable, you need to write a parser.

However, if you don't care, you should do something completely different: Use serialization, e.g. from [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html).

A third alternative for your case, which is quite common for games, is to store the map as an image file. You can then edit the map in your favorite image manipulation program, and it is easily interpreted by your program.
Many libs can read image data for you (and present it to you as a 2-D array), and in a game you maybe have something like that already in place.